# Desserialização de string

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

Peguei pelo Retrofit o campo Drivers do seguinte json:

```
{
  "Drivers": [
    {
      "DriverID": 0,
      "Latitude": -23.642276336,
      "Longitude": -46.634615118
    },
    {
      "DriverID": 1,
      "Latitude": -23.64227916,
      "Longitude": -46.634592381
    }
  ],
  "Success": true
}
```

Eu tenho uma list:

```
List drivers = MyModel.getDrivers();
```

Então fiz um drivers.get(0).toString() e obti a seguinte String:

```
{DriverID=0.0, Latitude=-23.642259377, Longitude=-46.634618813}
```

Agora eu quero fazer um deserialize nessa list para eu ter algo do tipo:

```
driver.getDriverID()
```

Tentei desta forma, mas não deu certo:

Código principal:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Drivers>>(){}.getType();
String str = drivers.get(0).toString();
List<Drivers> teste = (List<Drivers>) gson.fromJson(str, listType);
```

Drivers.java:

```
public class Drivers {
    @SerializedName("DriverID")
    private Integer DriverID;

    public Integer getDriverID() {  
        return DriverID;
    }

    public void setDriverID(Integer driverID) {
        DriverID = driverID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Drivers>>(){}.getType();
String str = drivers.get(0).toString();
Drivers teste =   gson.fromJson(str, Drivers.class);
teste.getDriverID();
```

Como você pega apenas um item da lista:

```
String str = drivers.get(0).toString();
```

Ele será apena o elemento dela:

```
{DriverID=0.0, Latitude=-23.642259377, Longitude=-46.634618813}
```

Então seu resultado será um `Drivers`

Comment: Eu estava tão focado em pegar com Array que havia esquecido que era muito mais fácil pegar como Objeto. Obrigado! Só acrescentei no drivers.class o getLatitude e getLongitude e estava funcionando exatamente como eu queria.

Obs: o listType não precisa ser usado neste caso, então tirei essa linha

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que você está colocando um `objeto` dentro de um `array`.

Tendo em vista que, `drivers.get(0)` retorna um **objeto Driver**, seu código precisa ficar algo parecido com:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String str = drivers.get(0).toString();
Drivers driver = gson.fromJson(str, Drivers.class);
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, era bem mais fácil fazer por Objeto e eu tentando usar Array. No seu exemplo só faltou colocar o getDriverID que o Thiago Luiz citou